# Google Maps API input Town Name instead of Lon and Lat

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a business listing website for a large tourist destination with a number of towns. The domain name is the same as the area and if I type into Google maps the area and the town Google maps gets the correct town every time.

When people sign up they have to enter a town at least but they can then enter an address also later and if I type that into Google maps I get a pin and street view, even better.

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        demo.add(function () {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap({
                'center': '-38.342529,144.955333', 'zoom': 10, 'disableDefaultUI': true, 'callback': function () {
                    var self = this;
                    self.addMarker({ 'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function () {
                        self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello World!' }, this);
                    });
                }
            });
        }).load();
    });
</script>
```

Right now I can dynamically populate the Lon and Lat via the database but I or the person listing their business has to put that in manually.

Is there a way I can change the above code so the value would be town name? Then I could do some if statements once they put in an address to have Google add the pin and street view. Can this be done?

Comment: You want the [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to translate an address to coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, new to Google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example, you can directly display the pin without knowing the Lat and Longitute, this process is called Geocoding

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Guys stop marking me down I've done it thanks...lol, just couldn't find it on google